# HTML scroll only one cell

Tags: html, css, html-table, spacing

I've got a problem in HTML. I have to make a table that fills the entire page, so you won't need to scroll it down, but there will be a cell that will almost certainly contain long text, so it must be scrollable.

The table is structured this way:

```
+------------------------------------------+
| Space 1 (fixed height, 20px, 100% width) |
|------------------------------------------|
| Space 2      |                           |
| 25% width    | Space 3                   |
| Scrollable   | Fills the remaining space |
|              |                           |
|              |                           |
|              |                           |
|              |                           |
|              |                           |
|              |                           |
|              |---------------------------|
|              | Space 4 (20px height)     |
+------------------------------------------+
```

I've done this code so far: http://jsfiddle.net/M98wS/2

```
<table class="questionsTable">
<col width="25%" />
<col width="25%" />
<col width="25%" />
<col width="25%" />
<tr>
    <td class="questionTitle" height="20px" colspan="4">Space 1 (fixed height, 20px)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="questionsList" rowspan="2">Space 2 (scrollable, 25% width, fixed height in page)
        <br/>Space 2
        <br/>Space 2
        <br/>Space 2
        <br/>Space 2
        <br/>Space 2
        <br/>Space 2
        <br/>Space 2
        <br/>Space 2
        <br/>Space 2
        <br/>Space 2
        <br/>Space 2
        <br/>Space 2
        <br/>Space 2
        <br/>Space 2
        <br/>Space 2
        <br/>Space 2
        <br/>Space 2
        <br/>Space 2
        <br/>Space 2
        <br/>Space 2
        <br/>Space 2
        <br/>Space 2
        <br/>Space 2
        <br/>Space 2
        <br/>Space 2
        <br/>Space 2
        <br/>Space 2
        <br/>Space 2
        <br/>Space 2
        <br/>Space 2
        <br/>Space 2
        <br/>Space 2
        <br/>Space 2
        <br/>Space 2
        <br/>Space 2
        <br/>Space 2
        <br/>Space 2
        <br/>Space 2
        <br/>Space 2
        <br/>Space 2
        <br/>
    </td>
    <td height="auto" colspan="3">Space 3 (fills the remaining space)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="questionActions" height="20px" colspan="4">Space 4 (fixed height, 20px)</td>
</tr>
```

```
html, body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
height:100%;
border:none;
}
table, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.questionsTable {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.questionsList {
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.questionTitle .questionActions {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Couldy you please ask a clear question!

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html?rq=1 It gives reasons why not to use tables for layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've removed the `overflow-y:scroll;` for `.questionsList`, and wrapped the td contents with a div that has an id of "scroll". Then added this css: `#scroll {overflow-y:scroll;height:100%;}`

See the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/M98wS/3/

HTML:

```
<table class="questionsTable">
    <col width="25%" />
    <col width="25%" />
    <col width="25%" />
    <col width="25%" />
    <tr>
        <td class="questionTitle" height="20px" colspan="4">Space 1 (fixed height, 20px)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="questionsList" rowspan="2">
            <div id="scroll">
            Space 2 (scrollable, 25% width, fixed height in page)
            <br/>Space 2
            <br/>Space 2
            <br/>Space 2
            <br/>Space 2
            <br/>Space 2
            <br/>Space 2
            <br/>Space 2
            <br/>Space 2
            <br/>Space 2
            <br/>Space 2
            <br/>Space 2
            <br/>Space 2
            <br/>Space 2
            <br/>Space 2
            <br/>Space 2
            <br/>Space 2
            <br/>Space 2
            <br/>Space 2
            <br/>Space 2
            <br/>Space 2
            <br/>Space 2
            <br/>Space 2
            <br/>Space 2
            <br/>Space 2
            <br/>Space 2
            <br/>Space 2
            <br/>Space 2
            <br/>Space 2
            <br/>Space 2
            <br/>Space 2
            <br/>Space 2
            <br/>Space 2
            <br/>Space 2
            <br/>Space 2
            <br/>Space 2
            <br/>Space 2
            <br/>Space 2
            <br/>Space 2
            <br/>Space 2
            <br/>Space 2
            <br/>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td height="auto" colspan="3">Space 3 (fills the remaining space)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="questionActions" height="20px" colspan="4">Space 4 (fixed height, 20px)</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
    border:none;
}
table, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.questionsTable {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.questionsList {
    overflow-x: auto;
}
.questionTitle .questionActions {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 20px;
}
#scroll {overflow-y:scroll;height:100%;}
```